# Ethereum testnet used for "production"

Tags: testnets

We are integrating a really simple Blockchain feature to our Nodejs and Angular APP.

The feature is that if a user is happy with the "item", they can generate a certificate and store the data of the certificate to the blockchain. Later I need to display the data of the certificate fetched from the blockchain in the Angular web app.

So my main question is, *can we use a testnet (maybe Morden) for production use and have some backup in our local database?*

Is it even possible to lose the data from testnet or that some person resets the Morden testcase?

What do you guys suggest for my case?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I wouldnt suggest the use of a testnet because testnets can also be deprecated or used to test breaking changes on the mainnet, so they won't be reliable.

You could use [Polygon Edge](https://polygon.technology/solutions/polygon-edge) to create your own chain, or in other words is a modular and extensible framework for building private or public Ethereum-compatible blockchain networks.

This way you have the blockchain technology available and its your own, meaning will be reliable.

Check their [docs](https://wiki.polygon.technology/docs/edge/overview/) for more information.

**Disclaimer: Am not affiliate to Polygon.

Answer (score 1):

> can we use a testnet (maybe Morden) for production use and have some backup in our local database?

You cannot, because it is guaranteed any testnet never works on any particular day. For example, transactions not going through or nodes not syncing.

If you want to use database, then use database. Don't use any blockchain if it is not a good solution for your problem.

Comment: What if our system administrator deploys our own Etherum blockchain in our private server? And I connect our app to private etherum blockchain?

Comment: I think the question would still stand: Why are you using a blockchain in this case? Blockchains are poor substitutes for databases.